# Specific text search in SQL?

Tags: postgresql

For an assignment, we are doing select statements using Shakespeare's works in PG Admin. I must find which character, and in what work, said a specific phrase. I'm stuck with the following code:

```
select workid, charid from paragraph

where plaintext like 'rose'
```

In which I'm trying to find who said "A rose by any other name would smell as sweet." Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Because the line given isn't the same as written, the following query worked:

```
select workid, charid, wordcount from paragraph
where plaintext like '%rose%'
and plaintext like '%other%'
and plaintext like '%name%'
and plaintext like '%smell%'
and plaintext like '%sweet%';
```